# Creating a query that uses criteria from two tables?

Tags: mysql, date

I'm looking a way to make a query with 2 tables:

```
posts:
+----+-------------------- +
| ID | post_date           |
+----+---------------------+
| 1  | 2011-11-15 08:42:50 |
+----+---------------------+

meta:
+--------------------+------------+
| post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
+---------+----------+------------+
|    1    |    ip    |192.168.1.10| 
+---------+----------+------------+
```

So, I need to make a query which looks for a given IP and returns ID, but date of post must be at least 10 minutes old.

Here is a bad example:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM posts
WHERE ip = '192.168.0.1'
   AND post_date = '2011-11-15 08:32:50'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT p.ID FROM posts p, meta m 
  WHERE m.post_id=p.ID 
    AND m.meta_value='192.168.0.1' 
    AND p.post_date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT p.ID
    FROM posts p
        INNER JOIN meta m
            ON p.ID = m.post_id
    WHERE m.meta_key = 'ip'
        AND m.meta_value = '192.168.0.1'
        AND p.post_date < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

Comment: "post must be at least 10 minutes old..." - your answer is very time specific

Comment: @Bruce: So was the sample code posted. The question seemed to be more about how to accomplish the JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.ID from posts p
INNER JOIN meta m ON (p.ID=m.post_id)

WHERE
m.ip = '192.168.0.1'
   AND
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,p.post_date,now()) > 10
```